# How to hide submenu of Crudify menu

Tags: scala, lift

I have the following code and need to hide the Comment submenu to non-members of site.

```
 var menu = List(Menu.i("Home") / "index",
            Menu(Loc("Static", Link(List("static"), true, "/static/index"),"Static Content"))
               )
menu = menu ::: User.menus
menu = menu ::: Comment.menus 
menu = menu ::: Links.menus


 // def sitemapMutators = User.sitemapMutator
  LiftRules.setSiteMap(SiteMap(menu: _*))
```

I have already tried >> Hidden but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

add Hidden to the menu's LocParams by overriding the list in the extending object.

ie. override def showAllMenuLocParams = Hidden :: super.showAllMenuLocParams